# Background-gradient with hard stop renders incorrectly in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a html layout with a navigation bar at the top and a main content area below it, with a left and a right area. The top bar has a background gradient with a hard stop in it. The main content's right area (sidebar) has a background color that should line up with the gradient stop of of the navigation area, at 75%.

See [this](http://codepen.io/brunodbo/full/Hfrnq) for a simplified version of my layout. In Firefox and Safari this renders fine, but Chrome puts the gradient stop a little further than it should. I tried to use pixel values instead of percentages, but the behaviour stayed the same.

Any idea why this is happening, and suggested workarounds? Thanks!

Comment: I don't see any gradient in the example

Comment: The blue background of the top bar is the gradient.

Comment: It's a chrome bug that's been around for awhile now. They are probably never going to fix it, it's stuff like this makes chrome a terrible browser

Answer (score 0):

Specially with modern browsers that deals with anti-aliasing in so different ways. What i have done was a js fix, (which wouldn't be good for your code :D) also you would have to add a custom padding for each element. But you'll need to hire a freelancer to do it for you, because it would take a while to complete (browser targeting, getting each element, adding padding for each element...)

if u can post the code it would be simple for more possibility.however i am looking for more solutions.